# MYSQL Format Data in a Column

Tags: mysql

I Have a question on formatting data in MYSQL.

This is how my table looks like

```
Table Movie
ID             Movie           Cast
1              Movie1          Actor1(Role1), Actor2(Role2), Actor3(Role3)
2              Movie2          Actor2(Role4), Actor3(Role1)
3              Movie3          Actor3(Role7), Actor5(Role9), Actor2(Role4)
```

I understand having multiple values in a field is bad database design and I am working on separating the values as well.

Can anyone helped me on removing the (Roles) from the column Cast? 
Is there anyway to check "(" and ")" and remove all characters in between the brackets?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Including the brackets themselves?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this function

http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=265

Answer (score 1):

This SQL function should get you going, from [a user comment in mysql's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), if you adjust for parenthesis instead of brackets.

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS strip_tags||
CREATE FUNCTION strip_tags( x longtext) RETURNS longtext LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE sstart INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE ends INT UNSIGNED;
SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
REPEAT
  SET ends = LOCATE('>', x, sstart);
  SET x = CONCAT(SUBSTRING( x, 1 ,sstart -1) ,SUBSTRING(x, ends +1 )) ;
  SET sstart = LOCATE('<', x, 1);
UNTIL sstart < 1 END REPEAT;
return x;
END;
||
delimiter ;

mysql> SELECT strip_tags('<a href="HelloWorld.html"><B>Hi, mate!</B></a>') as strip_tags;

+------------+`
| strip_tags |`
+------------+`
| Hi, mate!  |
+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this query 3 times and it will delete the 3 parenthesis and the content inside them.

I could've made it into one query, but I thought it would be too long and it would be harder to modify (error prone)

```
UPDATE table_name SET cast=REPLACE( cast ,  SUBSTRING(cast, LOCATE("(", cast)   , ( LOCATE(")", cast) - LOCATE("(", cast) +1  )) , ""     ) ;
```

If you split the query, you see that:

we get the length in characters between the opening and closing parenthesis, the +1 is there to include the closing parenthesis)

```
( LOCATE(")", cast) - LOCATE("(", cast) +1  )
```

Here we select the text from the cast column, starting at the first occurrence of ( and the length is taken from the line above snippet.

```
SUBSTRING(cast, LOCATE("(", cast)   , ( LOCATE(")", cast) - LOCATE("(", cast) +1  ))
```

Finally we use the REPLACE function, which takes the result of the previous line as parameters.

All those functions are documented here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace